# Lower casing and truncating a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert a variable to lower case and strip a suffix at the same time. The variable contains a file name and I am stripping the extension:

```
for f in *.shp; do echo ${f%.*};done
```

To convert a variable to lowercase I know the command is,

```
${f,,}
```

But how do I convert `${f%.*}` to lower case within the loop?

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ suits this better

Comment: Can it be migrated?

Comment: Probably not (have not seen it happen unless to meta).

Comment: @Rinzwind This is definitely off-topic on [programmers.se]. It would be on-topic on [so] and on [unix.se]. I'm surprised that you consider it off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

`for f in *.shp; do a=${f,,}; echo ${a%.*}; done`